# Do not show scroll button in second visit in Simple modal + slim scroll

Tags: jquery, simplemodal

I am using Simple modal "jquery.simplemodal.1.4.4.min.js" and slim scroll "jquery.slimscroll.min.js" to popup and make a div scroll. Everything is fine working when I get first popup but when I close that popup using $.modal.close() and again I open it then overflow scroll button is not showing and only the scroll bar is there.
What could be the problem ? Thanks in advance.

**Update**

Slim Scroll code:

```
$('#add_group_member_div').slimScroll({
 position: 'right',
 height: '130px',
 size: '10px',
 railVisible: true,
 alwaysVisible: true
});
```

Simple modal css code:

```
#simplemodal-container {
    width:709px; height: 464px;
    border: 4px solid #D0D2D3;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    -pie-background: #FFFFFF;
    border-radius:25px;
    display: none;
    position:relative;
    behavior: url("../css/groupmgmt/PIEFiles/PIE.htc");
}
```

Comment: So on the second visit you DON'T want it there?

Comment: On second visit also I need to display slim scroll overflow button, but it is not displaying. What could be the cause please ?

Comment: I'm a programmer, I'm not a miracle worker... I wouldn't be able to tell you unless I saw your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had faced & solved the issue by using pageLoad().

try this,

```
 function pageLoad() {
               $(function () {
                         $('#<%=ReportingEmployeesListPanel.ClientID %>').slimScroll({
                             position: 'right',
                             height: '500px',
                             width: '450px'
                         });
                     });
                 }
```